WPF application with map service and shape files
I try to develop a WPF application with a map for my personal use. I need to show shape file on the map and I need to handle selection to interact with it.
DO you know some solution ?
I try Syncfusion sfMap but it doesn't work well.
Thanks for your help
Nico

You may try the solutions mentioned here; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50541/reading-shapefile-using-c
Merry Xmas
